# developing Tool for Ext-Js 4

Tags: eclipse, extjs

I am using eclipse to develop an extjs based application with apache tomcat v6, and it seems to me like that the tool is **not** the best because sometimes (often) I have to restart the server to view changes in the browser even so I do small changes (js file). If you can advice me which tool is more convenient for Ext-Js (4.x) or tricks for eclipse.

Comment: just press ctrl+F5 to refresh the web page, browser will load your changed javascript code. You dont need to restart server

Comment: Yes I am ok with you, in my case I think that I have a problem with my {Tomcat+Eclipse} because they make more time to deploy changes. thank you for the response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up a way to disable page caching. You can do this through browser development tools (IE Developer Tools, Firebug, Chrome Development Tools, etc.) or through your server configuration.

In my work, we use a Java class that takes a list of JavaScript/CSS files and appends the request time as a Unix date to prevent the browser from caching. It then inserts the script tags into the page so the output looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js?_cb=20120319123456"></script>
```

So everything you access a page, the _cb param updates and it gets the new version of the file every time.

If you're already doing something like this and it isn't working, I would recommend switching to NetBeans. That's what I use and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MVC - which is brand-new feature of Ext JS 4 - you'll never need to restart or publish changes to application server. It always gets the updated file from file system.